# Alternative solutions to multilevel modelling due to level 2 and 3 not having enough clusters

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I have been running some multilevel models on my data but have now been told my clusters are too small and I need to consider taking out two of the levels and add them in as covaraites (dummy variables).I gave this a shot and it didn't work.

To provide some background information, I have pre and post test scores as the outcome variable. I have the data in long format. I have been using nlme package.

I have children nested within classes nested within schools. My original model included participant (n=303), class(n=17) and school(n=10) as three levels of MLM for random slopes but I also added time for random intercepts.
Based on the new advice to take out class and school due to the nested clusters not being large enough, I was going to keep the participants in as random slopes and time in as random intercepts.

I am fairly new to R and also finding my feet with stats so apologies if I have made some simple mistakes.

I guess my questions are: 1. Is the new technique of adding class and school as dummy variables the best approach? I have read about using FEMs (fixed effect models) to be a robust method for clustered data but was unsure if that is corresponding to the method I am actually trying to run 2. Is there a way to get back the issues with my model and the outputs I am getting (Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1) I found when i took out either class or code it worked, but this is not really a solution.

Any suggestions, solutions or guidance would be really appreciated, thank you.

Old Model:

model1 <- lme(MASSATTS ~ Time*Condition,
                data = cdata,
                method = "ML",
                na.action = "na.omit",
                random = ~ Time|School/Class/Code,
                control = list(opt = "optim"))
New Code:

model1 <- lme(MASSATTS ~ Time*Condition + School + Class,
                data = cdata,
                method = "ML",
                na.action = "na.omit",
                random = ~ Time|Code,
                control = list(opt = "optim"))
Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1